# How to fix template parameter as one enum class based on another template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, enums, c++17, sfinae

I have the following code where as of now, we have clothes, and footwear. But in future there can be many more item Object types. The class `Foo` is templated with `Object` and its member functions here are the same for both `eClothes` and `eFootwear`, but things are templated further in actual code.

Is there a way to deduplicate the implementation of method `order` ? Since there's a one to one mapping from

- Object::clothes -> eClothes
- Object::footwear -> eFootwear

.. Is there some technique that I can use to fix the template parameter of `order` based on `type` ?  So that one class instantiation accepts orders  of its corresponding kind only, otherwise it's a compile time error ?

```
#include<iostream>

enum class Object{
    clothes,
    footwear,
};
enum class eClothes{
    shirt,
};
enum class eFootwear{
    flipflop,
};

template <Object type>
class Foo{
    public:
    template<eClothes clothkind>
    void order(){
        std::cout << "hey\n";
    }

    template<eFootwear footwearkind>
    void order(){
        std::cout << "hey\n";
    }
};

int main(){
    Foo<Object::clothes> foo_clothes;
    Foo<Object::footwear> foo_footwear;
    foo_clothes.order<eClothes::shirt>();
    foo_footwear.order<eFootwear::flipflop>();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define [traits](https://www.boost.org/community/generic_programming.html#traits) that maps `Object` to its value type. Like:

```
template <Object value> struct ObjectTraits;
template <> struct ObjectTraits<Object::clothes>
{
    using type = eClothes;
};
template <> struct ObjectTraits<Object::footwear>
{
    using type = eFootwear;
};

template <Object type>
class Foo{
public:
    using Kind = typename ObjectTraits<type>::type;
    template<Kind kind>
    void order(){
        std::cout << "hey\n";
    }
};
```

To simplify a little  - you might use macro:

```
template <Object value> struct ObjectTraits;
#define OBJECT_TRAITS(value, kind) \
template <> struct ObjectTraits<Object::value> { \
    using type = kind; \
}

OBJECT_TRAITS(clothes , eClothes);
OBJECT_TRAITS(footwear, eFootwear);
```

Comment: Thanks! I was fiddling with creating a base struct, and then deriving from it where each derived struct will have the typedef. but derived's types are not visible from base. Traits is indeed the thing I was looking for. \\ In `Foo<eClothes>{}.order<eClothes::shirt>();`, where is the object instantiation that I can call methods of, pass around etc ?